# Flash 11.2 No Longer Supported by Google Play

Tags: flash, streaming, google, drm

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 on a laptop connected to my Plasma TV.  Google Play, up until today, worked really well streaming rights protected movies through Firefox using Flash 11.2. Unfortunately, not anymore.  They request you update your Flash player in order to stream movies. I downloaded and installed Google Chrome with the Flash Pepper API running Flash 11.7.  No luck, it has known issues supporting DRM on Linux. Stupid.  And yes, I do have HAL installed.

Does anyone have a solutions they can suggest?  In effect Flash 11.2 and Flash 11.7 won't work using Google Play. That kind of leaves us out in the woods.

Comment: So it's not just 11.2 as the title says but 11.7 as well? If that is correct, please edit the title.

Answer (score 0):

For some odd reason Firefox and the older Flash player (11.2) can once again stream Google-Play movies. I have no idea what changed over the last 24 hours... Was it just a glitch or maybe a reversed decision in regards to version requirements.  Anyway, I'm a happy man again. Fingers crossed this issue will remain fixed.